# How to manually delimit the number of displayed tows of a table (DataTables)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Is there any possibility to manually delimit the numbers of the displayed rows of a (Data)Table?

Normally we use filtering input, but then the values are fixed; for example: 10, 25, 50, 100, All.

I would like to have a text field where I could insert the number of rows I wish to display; for example: 3, 7, 29, etc and then after clicking a button we would display the "pages" of the table only with the inserted number of rows.

I read some tutorials and did some searches, but was unable to find anything about it.

Here the JavaScript of my table (but I don't think it helps):

```
$('#search-table').dataTable({
    "dom": "<'box-content'<'col-md-4'l><'col-md-8 text-right'f><'clearfix'>>rt<'box-content'<'col-md-5'i><'col-md-7 text-right'p><'clearfix'>>",

    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 8, 9, 10 ] }
    ],

    "aLengthMenu": [[50, 100, 500, -1], [50, 100, 500, "All"]],

    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",

    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": 'Filter within results: ',
        "sLengthMenu": '_MENU_'
    },
});
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from datatable forums.

```
var oTable;

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('YourButtonIdorSelector').click( function () {
        var newDisplayLength = $("TextFieldIDOrSelectorHere").val();
        var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
        oSettings._iDisplayLength = newDisplayLength;
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });

    oTable = $('#search-table').dataTable({
    "dom": "<'box-content'<'col-md-4'l><'col-md-8 text-right'f><'clearfix'>>rt<'box-content'<'col-md-5'i><'col-md-7 text-right'p><'clearfix'>>",

    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 8, 9, 10 ] }
    ],

    "aLengthMenu": [[50, 100, 500, -1], [50, 100, 500, "All"]],

    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",

    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": 'Filter within results: ',
        "sLengthMenu": '_MENU_'
    },
});

});
```

or

```
var searchTable = $('#search-table').dataTable({
    "dom": "<'box-content'<'col-md-4'l><'col-md-8 text-right'f><'clearfix'>>rt<'box-content'<'col-md-5'i><'col-md-7 text-right'p><'clearfix'>>",

    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 8, 9, 10 ] }
    ],

    "aLengthMenu": [[50, 100, 500, -1], [50, 100, 500, "All"]],

    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",

    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": 'Filter within results: ',
        "sLengthMenu": '_MENU_'
    },
});
searchTable.fnSettings()._iDisplayLength = $("TextFieldIDOrSelectorHere").val();
searchTable.fnDraw(); //redraw the table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the new length you want displayed to the `_iDisplayLength` property and redraw the table.

When creating the data table, this stuff would go in the complete callback function `fnInitComplete`

```
$('#search-table').dataTable({
    "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings,json){
        var $table = this;

        //example of how many rows to show
        var newLength = 29;         

        //add the new value to your datatable object
        oSettings._iDisplayLength = newLength;

        //redraw the table, you have to do this to see the changes
        $table.fnDraw();

    },
    //the rest of your settings
});
```